# From ModelAndView to Rest API Only - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, spring-mvc

I am writing a Java Spring Boot Web App which currently doesn't have a frontend framework. However, I plan to now write this using Angular. The backend endpoints, as of now, all return a type of ModelAndView, but now I would like to update them to return JSON responses. However, I'm not really familiar with how to go about doing so, and need some help doing so. I would like to provide an example of a current function I have below, and need some help rewriting it to return a JSON response instead.

```
    @PostMapping("/newRecord")
    ModelAndView newRecordPost(ModelAndView modelAndView, @ModelAttribute(value="newRecord")@Valid NewRecord newRecord, BindingResult result) {
        
        modelAndView.setViewName("app.newRecord");
        
        if(!result.hasErrors()) {
            newRecordService.save(newRecord);
            modelAndView.getModel().put("newRecord", new NewRecord());
            modelAndView.setViewName("app.newHardwareItems");
        }
        
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Or an even simpler one, like so:

```
    @RequestMapping("/invalidUser")
    ModelAndView invalidUser(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        modelAndView.getModel().put("message", invalidUserMessage);
        modelAndView.setViewName("app.message");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

The overall idea of returning a JSON response is something foreign to me, but this is what I've been directed to do. I'm more familiar with the MVC concepts, so any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Just `return newRecord`. Essentially, "turn this object into JSON" becomes the universal View.

Comment: Please see the question updated above. What would I return and how would I change the function in this situation?

Comment: You return a POJO representing whatever JSON you want sent to the client. Spring will turn it into JSON (or potentially XML, or other bits, as the client requests in `Accept`).